# How to stop double sending the headers in node express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm receiving error "Can't set headers after they are sent to the client". and i found out the my code are trying to send 2 response that trying to modify the previous set of headers.

To solve the issue I put return keyword to stop the function execution and stop the 2nd "res". however is there a fancier way or more node express way to do it?

here is my current solution.

```
if(!err && goal) {
                if(goal.currentValue >= goal.targetValue) {//check if status is completed currentValue >= targetValue
                    models.Goal.findOneAndUpdate(
                        { _id: goal._id },
                        { $set: { isCompleted: true }},
                        { useFindAndModify: false, new: true },
                        (err, goal) => {

                            if(err)  res.status(500).json({ message: `Update failed. ${err}`});
                            else if(goal.isCompleted) res.status(200).json({ message: 'Goal is completed' });
                        });
                        return  //I used return to stop from executing the 2nd calling of res.status(200)....               
                }
                res.status(200).json({ message: `Goal progress has been updated`});
            }
```

Comment: Your final `res.status(200)` is *always* executed, and before your `(err, goal) => ...` callback is.

Comment: yes thats why i added the return keyword after the callback.. my question is how to do this in more fancy way using node express?. code above is working now. just want to enchance it @deceze

Comment: IMO `res.status(200).json({ message: "Goal progress has been updated"});` this is not required altogether. Because anyways u're sending response after checking updated doc.

Answer (score 0):

Try out by putting `else` .

```
       if(!err && goal) {
            if(goal.currentValue >= goal.targetValue) 
{//check if status is completed currentValue >= targetValue
                                    models.Goal.findOneAndUpdate(
                                        { _id: goal._id },
                                        { $set: { isCompleted: true }},
                                        { useFindAndModify: false, new: true },
                                        (err, goal) => {

                                            if(err)  res.status(500).json({ message: `Update failed. ${err}`});
                                            else if(goal.isCompleted) res.status(200).json({ message: 'Goal is completed' });
                               else{
                                   res.status(200).json({ message: `Goal progress has been updated`});
                                }
                                        });

                                }


                            }
```